# Comparison operators with date and timestamp data types in Pymongo and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, time-series, pymongo, querying

```py
import pymongo

from pymongo import MongoClient
```

I am using the following test code for time-series related queries:

```
db = client['sample_weatherdata']
collection = db['data']
collection.find_one() ['ts']
```

returning this result:

```
datetime.datetime(1984, 3, 5, 14, 0)
```

When I am applying filters, which are syntactically correct, for the **find** operator I receive empty lists. An example of the time series data values, field 'ts' in the collection, is as follows:

```
`_id: 5553a998e4b02cf7151190ba
st: "x+51900+003600"
ts: 1984-03-05T14:00:00.000+00:00`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what find query are you running?

Comment: For instance:    mysearch1 = list(collection.find({"ts": {'$gte': 'ISODate(1984,3,5)'}}))
mysearch1

Comment: Same effect with other than ISODate functions...Tried without apostrophes, for instance, collection.find({"ts": {'$gte': ISODate(1984,3,5)}}, and receive error message like NameError: name 'ISODate' is not defined

Comment: And also with the $toDate and $Date operators...mysearch1 = list(collection.find({"ts": {'$gte': {'$toDate': (1984-3-5)}}}))....

Answer (score 0):

To query a `date` field in pymongo, pass in a `datetime.datetime`, e.g.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

client = MongoClient()
db = client['sample_weatherdata']
collection = db['data']

collection.insert_one({'st': "x+51900+003600",
                       'ts': datetime.datetime(1984, 3, 5, 14, 0)})

print(list(collection.find({"ts": {'$gte': datetime.datetime(1984, 3, 5)}})))
```

prints:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('62cc6b80d82e6ba8f9059379'), 'st': 'x+51900+003600', 'ts': datetime.datetime(1984, 3, 5, 14, 0)}]
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that one, however, the [datetime] cannot be imported, although [import MongoClient] works fine. Every time I try to import and use datetime I receive the following error message: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15652/2960346256.py in <module>
      1 import pymongo
      2 from pymongo import MongoClient
----> 3 from pymongo import datetime

ImportError: cannot import name 'datetime' from 'pymongo' (C:\Users\*****\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\__init__.py)

Comment: By the way, I am connecting with a MongoDB database and collection on the cloud....

Comment: It's `import datetime` not `from pymongo import datetime`. `datetime` is a standard library.